# How can I check if a value exists already in a Firebase data class Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the bus number already exists in the database of Firebase.

Here's my sample code. I've been searching for the past days but I can't find the right code to do so.

```
ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
postRef = ref.child("BusNumber");

busNum = edtBus.getText().toString().trim();
route1 = route.trim();
seat = edtSeat.getText().toString().trim();

if (!busNum.isEmpty() && !route1.isEmpty() && !seat.isEmpty()) {
    postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(busNum).exists()) {
                edtBus.setError("Bus number already exists.");
                edtBus.setText("");
            } else {
                busNumber = new BusNumber();
                busNumber.setBusNum(busNum);
                busNumber.setRoute(route1);
                busNumber.setNumSeat(seat);
                postRef.push().setValue(busNumber);
                edtBus.setText("");
                edtSeat.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(AddBusActivity.this, "Saving successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(AddBusActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(AddBusActivity.this, firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

} else {
    Toast.makeText(AddBusActivity.this, "Please complete the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Can somebody help me with this matter? Thanks in advance.
Whether the if statement is correct or not, also my problem is why does the `postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`...doesn't work? I tried to test some toast message but the message won't pop out.

[image: here is my firebase database]

Comment: do you have any firebase rules setup preventing you from reading the database? Maybe add a Log in the onCanceled and print out the firebase error if there is one.

Comment: @linxy yes I already did. But as far as I can remember. There was no error

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: this because you did not use the calback function and interface i have also the same problem as your that for ( datasnap shot /....) full method did not work it just give whether the null value or null object reference or you did not get the desired value see the link of my question .. and a nice person guide me by giving me the link .. the first one link helped me i use callback and interface trick.
[Whey your code firebase database did not work click this hyperlink ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582992/get-all-table-values-from-firebase-null-object-reference-firebase-database)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.

When you are doing this `dataSnapshot.child(busNum).exists()`, it's looking for the `busNum` in the key section, where your keys are `-kasajdh...`.

So instead what you can do is, get the `iterable`, now when you look for
`data.child(busNum).exists()` it relates to the value

```
   postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (data.child(busNum).exists()) {
                        //do ur stuff
                    } else {
                       //do something if not exists
                    }
                  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 16):

Rather than getting whole iterable list of data, you can query for exact entry.

```
  postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BusNumber");

    postRef.orderByChild("busNum").equalTo(busNum)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

           @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                   //bus number exists in Database
            } else {
                //bus number doesn't exists.
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dataSnapshot.child(busNum).getValue() != null
```

should work.

Comment: but it doesn't work. Even if I try to toast some message inside the onDataChange method, there would never pop out a message.

Comment: Check your Firebase auth rules maybe? The rules might be preventing you from doing so.

Comment: But I'm not creating a new user. It's stored in the database. Do I still need to check my auth rules?

Comment: sorry, i meant your database rules, not auth

Comment: Another problem might be that you're using old Firebase so it might be deprecated?

Comment: but this is my database rules `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}`

Comment: Then my best guess is what I said above. Maybe Firebase might not support the old version any more.

Comment: I see, I tried to update my firebase to the latest version of 9.4.0. But I can't check it yet coz i'm still downloading/updating my SDK google repo

Comment: hi @Abhi I already put some image of the firebase database structure. I hope that helped. And also, you're right. Firebae does not support the old version. But the thing is ... this code snippet `dataSnapshot.child(busNum).getValue() != null` didn't work. It will save the as new BusNumber data in Firebase

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to guess the problem because you do not show how `busNum` and `busNumber` are defined and managed.  Is `busNumber` a String?

`push()` creates a reference to an auto-generated child location.  The auto-generated key looks something like `-KPB_cS74yoDaKkM9CNB`.

The statement  `postRef.push().setValue(busNumber)` stores value `busNumber` in location `BusNumber/<push-generated-key>`.

The statement `dataSnapshot.child(busNum).exists()` tests for the existence of a value at location `BusNumber/<busNum>`.  It will not be true unless `busNum` is one of the keys created by `push()`.

It's not clear how you want your data structured.  If your bus numbers are Strings and are unique, you do not need to generate a key with `push()`.  You could store the existence of bus numbers using:

`postRef.child(busNumber).setValue(true)`

Comment: I don't understand why I need to setValue(true).. All I wanna do is to check if the bus number already exist in the database. cause if the bus number exist it will prompt but if not it will create an new set of bus in the database

Comment: @tin: Is `busNumber` a String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752247/how-to-check-already-existed-email-in-firebase-database

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(busNum).exists()))
```

and then hashmap object

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.