# Check if a key already exist in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have some problems related to my database, and the docs seems a lot of confusing i can't figure out how to solve that, basicly i have my user data in the firebase, and i want to see if in my user with some id i already have the key username if yes i want to update with some data of my form, if no i want to add a value based on my form, but when i want to know how to check if the id already exist, i did this:

```
  auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();
        userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        user =  myRef.child("Users").child(userId);
        Log.d("test1",String.valueOf(user.child("age").getKey()));
        if(user.child("username").co){
            usernameTxt.setText(user.child("username").toString());
        }
        if(user.child("age") != -1){
            usernameTxt.setText(user.child("age").toString());
        }
```

[image: data]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948905/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-exists-already-in-a-firebase-data-class-anroid

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase

Check these

Comment: what is that datasnapshot, i don't understand very well the docs

Comment: @Filipe can you post your sample database tree.

Comment: updated data up

Comment: i don't understand very well what i need to do basicly i want to insert the username if it not exist and update if it exist

Comment: atm that username is not there

Comment: are you using google login

Comment: no atm im simple using normal login and created a new child where i register a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("username")){
                //IT EXISTS
            }
            else{
                //IT DOESNT EXISTS
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i feel i almost did it, but how can i retrive a single value of snapshot? i did this: dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(), inspected that with logcat and it gives me this: https://friendlymanager-3b7a2.firebaseio.com/Users/g7LWSXBP2WYwBbDqPS82oEpILA22/username :S

Comment: You have to cast it use getValue(String.class);

Comment: Have you tested my answer?

Comment: yeah i did it, i will accept the answer, a last question, i have a User model in a separate file and i save the data using it, i saw some examples where they use the dataSnapshot with the model, in this case can i do it to do a better approach?´

Comment: Do you want to get the data or write it?

Comment: i want to get it to display on my activity, and then when i press update data, add or update the data on firebase, but in this example i just want to get

Comment: Use getValue (Yourmodel.class) in the dataSnaphot

Comment: can i add you to chat ?

Comment: Yes, i dont have any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141583/discussion-between-filipe-costa-and-martin-de-simone).