# get all table values from firebase null object reference firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nullreferenceexception, null-object-pattern

```
public class ShowBPGraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public GraphView graphView;
public LineGraphSeries <DataPoint>lineGraphSeries; 
public String systolicbp;
public String diastolicbp;
public String timebp;
public String datebp;

public DatabaseReference db;
public BPFragmentTable bpFragmentTable = new BPFragmentTable(  );

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_show_bp_graph );
    ButterKnife.bind( this );

     db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bpfragmentTable");

    final GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById( R.id.graphView );

    final List<BPFragmentTable> bpFragmentTableList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Get datasnapshot at your "users" root node
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bpfragmentTable");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<BPFragmentTable> bpfragmentTableList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        BPFragmentTable bpfragmentTable = dataSnapshot1.getValue(BPFragmentTable.class);

                        systolic = bpfragmentTable.getSystolicbp();
                        diastolic = bpfragmentTable.getDiastolicbp();
                        date = bpfragmentTable.getDatebp();
                        time = bpfragmentTable.getTimebp();
                        //bpfragmentTable.setSystolicbp(systolic);
                        //bpfragmentTable.setDiastolicbp(diastolic);
                        //bpfragmentTable.setDatebp(date);
                        //bpfragmentTable.setTimebp(time);
                        bpfragmentTableList.add(bpfragmentTable);
                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
// please help me why i get null value in systolic diastolic date and time

            System.out.println( "systolicbp" + systolicbp );
            System.out.println( "diastolicbp" + diastolicbp );
            System.out.println( "datebp" + datebp );
            System.out.println( "timebp" + timebp );

    try {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a\nMMM dd yyyy");
        dateValued = formatter.parse(datebp);
        dateInMills = dateValued.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final long xlong = dateInMills;
    final int ysystolicInt  = Integer.parseInt( systolicbp );
    final int ydiastolicInt = Integer.parseInt( diastolicbp );
```

this is the error in the picture

[image: getting null object reference from firebase database]

I want to get `bpfragmentTable` all values and store all values in the string variable and use that variable to draw a graph in the graph view. I want to get all values from the table-BPFragment table  in the picture:

[image: FireBase DataBase bpfragmentTable]

and this is the class of getter and setter of BPFragmentTable.class

```
public class BPFragmentTable {

public String bpid;
public String systolicbp;
public String diastolicbp;
public String datebp;
public String timebp;

public BPFragmentTable(){}
public BPFragmentTable(String bpid,String systolicbp,String diastolicbp,String datebp,String timebp) {

     this.bpid = bpid;
     this.systolicbp = systolicbp;
     this.diastolicbp = diastolicbp;
     this.datebp = datebp;
     this.timebp = timebp;

}

public String getBpid() {
    return bpid;
}

public void setBpid(String  bpid) {
    this.bpid = bpid;
}

public String getSystolicbp() {
    return systolicbp;
}

public void setSystolicbp(String systolicbp) {
    this.systolicbp = systolicbp;
}

public String getDiastolicbp() {
    return diastolicbp;
}

public void setDiastolicbp(String diastolicbp) {
    this.diastolicbp= diastolicbp;
}

public String getDatebp() {
    return datebp;
}

public void setDatebp(String datebp) {
    this.datebp= datebp;
}

public String getTimebp() {
    return timebp;
}

public void setTimebp(String timebp) {
    this.timebp= timebp;
} 
}
```

Why do I get null object reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time you call `formatter.parse(datebp)` the `onDataChange` method hasn't run yet, and `datebp` hasn't been set. You will need to move the parsing of the data **into** `onDataChange`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bpfragmentTable");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<BPFragmentTable> bpfragmentTableList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            BPFragmentTable bpfragmentTable = dataSnapshot1.getValue(BPFragmentTable.class);

            systolic = bpfragmentTable.getSystolicbp();
            diastolic = bpfragmentTable.getDiastolicbp();
            date = bpfragmentTable.getDatebp();
            time = bpfragmentTable.getTimebp();
            bpfragmentTableList.add(bpfragmentTable);

            System.out.println( "systolicbp" + systolicbp );
            System.out.println( "diastolicbp" + diastolicbp );
            System.out.println( "datebp" + datebp );
            System.out.println( "timebp" + timebp );

            try {
                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a\nMMM dd yyyy");
                dateValued = formatter.parse(datebp);
                dateInMills = dateValued.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

This asynchronous nature is a common pitfall for developers new to Firebase. Since asynchronous APIs are extremely common in modern programming, I highly recommend you learn about them quickly. For some good introductory material, see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519) (which also shows how to use an interface to get the values out of `onDataChange`)
- this [blog post on asynchronous APIs](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener) (where I explained how in some cases you can get synchronous data loading, but usually can't)

Comment: thank you so much respectful sir for your answer and i am applying the change as you said

Comment: no sir when i put it formatter.parse(datebp) inside the onDataChange then same error null object reference mean still null values in system.out.println

Comment: i think my solution is inside your first link (getContactsFromFirebase()) i am reading it and now i understand that why i keep getting null values and but i need to make that code acording to my code

Comment: thank you so much your link helped me alot and i now i did get a null value because of call back method

Comment: acctually sir i clicked the up vote when you give me the first link it did not show my vote because i am new in Stack OverFlow and i must have 15 reputation to up Vote any answer ... i am so sorry sir and thank you so much for the big big big help thank you so much sir i never forget your help May you live long and good life Sir